# Full size <main> with footer pushed to the bottom

Tags: html, css, web

My page is divided in to 3 pieces. The `<header>`, the `<main>` and the `<footer>`.

The `<header>` is fixed to the top and is 109px with its 6px border high so the `<main>` has a 109px margin to the top.

I want the `<main>` to extend over the entire page below the `<header>` and to the `<footer>` that should, if no content that is available to push it down, rest on the bottom of the screen and the `<main>` should extend to the `<footer>` even if there is no content to extend the size for the `<main>` to put a background image.

The `<footer>` is 86px high because it is 80px and 6px for a border at the top.

To have the `<footer>` pushed down I have to set `min-hight: 100%;` on the body but to have a full screen background image on the `<main>` I have to set `height: 100%;` on the body but then the footer stays at the position where the bottom of the screen was before scrolling.

How can I fix this problem?

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  /* or min-hight: 100% */
}

#in {
  width: 1000px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 100%;
}


/* ---------------------------------------------------------------- */

#all {
  height: 100%;
}

#fullmain {
  padding-top: 109px;
  padding-bottom: 86px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #f5f5f5 url(" http://pre06.deviantart.net/2bf3/th/pre/i/2010/284/b/d/autumn_fortest_ii_by_lotusonlinede-d30jn9b.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100%
}

#header {
  background-color: #25211e;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #1d1a18;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 103px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  z-index: 99;
}

#heading {
  font-family: "titlefont";
  color: #c1b497;
  font-size: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}


/* ---------------------------------------------------------------- */

#footer {
  background-color: #25211e;
  border-top: 6px solid #1d1a18;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 98;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
}

#credit {
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #c1b497;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div id="all">
  <header id="header">
    <h1 id="heading">My Page</h1>
  </header>
  <main id="fullmain">

  </main>
  <footer id="footer">
    <p id="credit">Footer</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: I see that you have a lot of different issues with your code layout and ask many questions. May I ask one; which browsers do you need to support?

Comment: only the newer versions of common ones so Firefox, Chrome...

Comment: https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what your are looking for? Your question is not clear.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  /* or min-hight: 100% */
}

#in {
  width: 1000px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 100%;
}


/* ---------------------------------------------------------------- */

#all {
  height: 100%;
}

#fullmain {
  padding-top: 109px;
  padding-bottom: 86px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #f5f5f5 url(" http://pre06.deviantart.net/2bf3/th/pre/i/2010/284/b/d/autumn_fortest_ii_by_lotusonlinede-d30jn9b.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: calc(100% - 195px);
}

#header {
  background-color: #25211e;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #1d1a18;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 103px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  z-index: 99;
}

#heading {
  font-family: "titlefont";
  color: #c1b497;
  font-size: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}


/* ---------------------------------------------------------------- */

#footer {
  background-color: #25211e;
  border-top: 6px solid #1d1a18;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 98;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
}

#credit {
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #c1b497;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div id="all">
  <header id="header">
    <h1 id="heading">My Page</h1>
  </header>
  <main id="fullmain">

  </main>
  <footer id="footer">
    <p id="credit">Footer</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```